# Trouble with compiler and linker flags to compile free standing C++ code (independent of std and OS) for visual studio 2022

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, compiler-errors, linker-errors

I am trying to write a free standing C++ code that should be independent from any environment, something like bare metal code. In order to do this I found [this project](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36907/How-to-develop-your-own-Boot-Loader)
this project. However things changed a little bit in visual studio 2022.

These are my compiler flags:

```
/GS /GY /GL /clr:nostdimport /clr:nostdlib /Zl *.cpp
```

These are my linker flags:

```
/ENTRY:Test /NODEFAULTLIB /MACHINE:x64  *.obj
```

And this is the only cpp file in my solution:

```
#include <cstdint>
int32_t Test()
{
int64_t Var1 = 0;
Var1++;
return 0;
}
```

When I am tryin to compile the project, the linker complains the entry point is not defined.

```
fatal error LNK1561: entry point must be defined
```

While clearly I defined it. Why won't my code compile?
I really appreciate any help.

Edit: For more information I do not want `main` to be an entry point clearly!

Comment: You need a `main()` function to build an executable program. VTC as typo,

Comment: Clearly I do not want main to be my entry point! I want it to be a test function, did you even look at the linked project?

Comment: Then you'll need to provide your own startup assembly code, and use that for linking.

Comment: Another question: Are you cross-compiling?

Comment: Name mangling trouble perhaps? Try adding an `extern "C"` to the function.

Comment: ^ there should be a .MAP plain text file showing the mangling

Comment: Changed definition to `extern "C" int32_t Test()` still getting the same error!

Comment: If I change compilation flags to the linked project flags `/AT /G2 /Gs /Gx /c /Zl *.cpp` the error will become `LNK1221: a subsystem can't be inferred and must be defined`. So maybe I need set proper compilation flags somehow?!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ -- no, `main` is not necessarily required in a freestanding program. It's implementation-defined what the entry point is, and a command-line flag like `/ENTRY:` pretty strongly suggests that the user can specify the name of the entry point.

Comment: For those who haven't come across this before, there are **two** kinds of implementations specified for C and C++: hosted and freestanding. Most of us write programs for a hosted implementation: the entry point is named `main` and you have access to the full standard library. A freestanding implementation, in contrast, is intended for embedded systems; it comes with a possibly smaller standard library and doesn't have to have `main` (it's implementation-defined what the entry point for a freestanding program is).

Comment: The problem was related to `/c`, because the compiler generates only .obj files and does not call linker immediately if it uses this flag. However, now linker complains I should tell it what the subsystem is. There is no subsystem in my case, but it tells me I should define it. If I set it to `WINDOWS` would it affect machine code in the `.txt` section? Can I just rip them and use them? Or any other way to use some linker script(like OSDev wiki scripts)?
This is logical though, since I want to generate a PE I have to choose a subsystem, but what if I want just .obj files linked together?

Answer (score 0):

Posting temporary answers in case someone had this problem in future. As I mentioned, the problem was related to the `/c` flag. We use this flag to only generate `.obj` files and in the final stage link all of them. The other problem that will arise after fixing this problem is that linker will force you to choose a subsystem type. As I google it seems there is not much you could do with visual studio, also visual studio is going to add the `.pdata` section into final PE. However, checking generated code in the `'.txt'` section with IDAPro, it seems like the opcodes could be used as freestanding code if you extract them from there manually.
I will update my answer if I find a better solution or any specific problem happened by extraction opcodes manually.
Final Compiler flags that I used:

```
ml64.exe /c *.asm
cl.exe /c /GS /GL /clr:nostdimport /clr:nostdlib /Zl *.cpp
```

Final Linker flags that I used:

```
link.exe /ENTRY:Test /NODEFAULTLIB /MACHINE:x64 /DYNAMICBASE:NO /FIXED /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /OUT:FinalStub.exe *.obj
```

PS: MASM (`ml64.exe`) in my case can't find `*.asm` files, so I have to add files manually while `ml.exe` can. If someone knows how to fix this I would really appreciate it if you could write a solution in the comments.